# How to prevent children of a Bootstrap collapse resizing as the collapse collapses

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

The page I'm working on needs a collapsible element which I implemented with a Bootstrap horizontal collapse. In it there is a table. As the collapse collapses the table squishes and increases in height, both the table itself and each row, meaning the transition doesn't look smooth. This is especially noticeable when the element un-collapses since the rows don't resize till the collapse is fully expanded.

How do I keep the table consistent during the animation?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="item-statcard item-number w-25">
  <p class="">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#statcard-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="statcard-collapse">Statistics</button>
  </p>
  <div class="">
    <div class="collapse collapse-horizontal show" id="statcard-collapse" style="float: right;">
      <div class="card card-body statcard-body">
        <table id="statcard-table" class="texte_principal_small table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
          <tbody class="">
            <tr class="">
              <td colspan="2" class="">
                <h2 class="">Table</h2>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="" width="40%">Dimensions (L-w-h)</td>
              <td class="">8.5 x 3.23 x 2.75 m</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Total weight</td>
              <td class="">28 tonnes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Crew</td>
              <td class="">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="" valign="top">Propulsion</td>
              <td class="">diesel engine</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Speed</td>
              <td class="">50 km/h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Range</td>
              <td class="">420 km</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Total production</td>
              <td class="">2020+</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It does for me, yes, when the result is shown in full page. For example the three measurements move to new lines, dynamically as the table collapses and go back to a single line only when the table is fully expanded.

Comment: Unrelated: You shouldn't be using inline styles, and you definitely shouldn't use floats. Bootstrap has all the alignment you'll ever need built in, and floats are mostly obsolete.

Comment: I have all other styles in the appropriate CSS files, that one is there as I'm testing for a solution. The use of float itself is to get the collapse to (appear to) collapse from left to right rather than the regular opposite. Might not be the best solution but it is what I found after a quick search and seemed to be working for now. I also tested without it and still get the table resizing by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was apparently keeping the inline styling Bootstrap provides, namely  `style="width: 300px;"` for the card-body.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="item-statcard item-number w-25">
  <p class="">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#statcard-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="statcard-collapse">Statistics</button>
  </p>
  <div class="">
    <div class="collapse collapse-horizontal show" id="statcard-collapse" style="float: right;">
      <div class="card card-body statcard-body" style="width: 300px;">
        <table id="statcard-table" class="texte_principal_small table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
          <tbody class="">
            <tr class="">
              <td colspan="2" class="">
                <h2 class="">Table</h2>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="" width="40%">Dimensions (L-w-h)</td>
              <td class="">8.5 x 3.23 x 2.75 m</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Total weight</td>
              <td class="">28 tonnes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Crew</td>
              <td class="">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="" valign="top">Propulsion</td>
              <td class="">diesel engine</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Speed</td>
              <td class="">50 km/h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Range</td>
              <td class="">420 km</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <td class="">Total production</td>
              <td class="">2020+</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a fix. Don't forget to accept your answer.